# Building apk gives com.android.dex.dexexception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I just added a new dependency in my app: [Flubber](https://github.com/Appolica/Flubber). Now my app is working fine on instant run. But when I generate an apk, it gives me the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow;

Can you please tell me why is this happening ?

**Edit:**

Running with `--stacktrace` gives:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)

...

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow;
>       at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)

...

> Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow;

...

> Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow;

...

Comment: Post your gradle file it looks like there are duplicate libraries